# Thread-local storage variables in D, confusion about interaction with module initializers

Tags: d

Let's say I have some globals and some thread-local variables getting initialized (say, a TLS `a`, global `b`, TLS `c`, and global `d` initialized in that order) in a module's static this() and deinitialized in its static ~this().

Could someone please walk me through the steps taken by the program to initialize the variables in both single and multi-threaded applications?

Or correct me if I'm making a really really horrible assumption?

EDIT: To make it a little clearer:

```
module mymodule;
int a;
__gshared int b;
int c;
__gshared d;
static this()
{
  a = 2; b = 3; c = 4; d = 1337;
}
static ~this()
{
  if(a == 2)
    dosomefunc(b);
  // and other nonsensical things that involve branching on the TLS and using the globals.
}
```

What happens when I change the value of a in some thread that was spawned, but never touch it in the main thread? Is `dosomefunc()` ever called? What is the actual behavior supposed to be here, and what is that behavior *dependent* on? How are module initializers called with regards to TLS? Are they just called once and TLS vars get the shaft beyond some value initialization? What in the world do those two (de)initializers *mean*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of static constructors:

```
static this() { ... }
```

which gets run whenever a new thread is started. It's purpose is to initialize thread local storage (TLS) variables.

```
shares static this() { ... }
```

runs once on program startup, and it is used to initialize __gshared and other global data.

Comment: Typo, that should be "shared", not "shares"

Comment: Typo aside, this clears up a huuuuuge amount. I'm kind of scratching my head at how I managed to miss that in the language documentation. ._.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after digging around a lot more and writing a some test code, I *think* I've got a handle on it, sans the detail of __gshared variables.

From [here](http://dlang.org/class.html#StaticConstructor), the module static constructor is ran once per thread. Its static deconstructor is ran on thread return. Modules act sort of like per-thread pseudo-class 'instances', with their 'member' variables being their TLS variables, and their `__gshared` variables being like static variables for that class. In my mind, this forms the relationships

object:`class` :: `module`:[a logical collection of `__gshared` variables]

and

[no-qualifier]:`static` :: [no-qualifier]:`__gshared`

where the latter halves of each relationship are shaped by multithreading and the static constructors/destructors.

The hole left in my understanding, then, is how `__gshared` fits into module initialization.

Hopefully someone else comes up with a much better answer filling in that hole that I can accept.